# Does TextRecognitionModel from opencv support GPU mode?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've made the `TextDetectionModel` tutorial at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d43/tutorial_dnn_text_spotting.html work, and I'd like to speed up the detection with GPU by adding a couple of lines, but I'm hitting error.

The code I'm running is below, and I've commented the two lines that would lead to error

```py
import io

import PIL.Image
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import requests

# Downloaded following instruction from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d43/tutorial_dnn_text_spotting.html
db_model_path = (
    "/home/dev/disk/projects/learn/opencv/DB_TD500_resnet50.onnx"  # eng and ch
)

db_model = cv.dnn.TextDetectionModel_DB(db_model_path)

binThresh = 0.3
polyThresh = 0.5
maxCandidates = 200
unclipRatio = 2.0

(
    db_model.setBinaryThreshold(binThresh)
    .setPolygonThreshold(polyThresh)
    .setMaxCandidates(maxCandidates)
    .setUnclipRatio(unclipRatio)
)

scale = 1.0 / 255.0
mean = (122.67891434, 116.66876762, 104.00698793)
inputSize = (736, 736)

db_model.setInputParams(scale, inputSize, mean)

# These are the two lines that create error.
db_model.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
db_model.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)

response = requests.get("https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/detect_test1.jpg")

img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))

out = db_model.detect(np.asarray(img))
```

The error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/net_impl.cpp:119: error: (-215:Assertion failed) preferableBackend != DNN_BACKEND_CUDA || IS_DNN_CUDA_TARGET(preferableTarget) in function 'validateBackendAndTarget'
```

I wonder if `TextDetectionModel_DB` supports GPU mode? If so, what's the proper way to set it up?

Comment: You need to build OpenCV from source with CUDA support.

Comment: assertion says: *either* backend *isn't* CUDA, *or else it is* and *the target* is a cuda target -- you can grab *cudawarped*'s special cuda-enabled builds of opencv-python on his github